# docker argument not getting detected

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

**Problem**

I am trying to send a argument to dockerfile using `--build-arg` but my final `CMD` is not recognizing it.

**Code:**

```
docker image build -t *image_name* --build-arg env=${ENVIRONMENT} .
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim
VOLUME /tmp
ARG env
RUN echo ${env}
RUN echo "config-${env}.yml"

COPY configs/* ./
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081
CMD java -jar something server config-$env.yml
```

The kubernetes clusters are giving `CrashLoopBackOff`

**What I did:**

```
kubectl -n abc logs -p xyz
```

**Error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File config-.yml not found
```

Comment: You need to explicitly set it as an `ENV` variable to be usable in `CMD`.  (Or build a single image that can be used in all environments, and pass the environment variable at deploy time.)

Comment: thanks for the help